# Protection.setUnprotectedRanges complain about parameters not matching signature despite passing it the correct parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet-protection

In [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371859/setunprotectedranges-fails-in-google-app-script-with-the-parameters-number-d) I was helped to fix a mistake I made with the signature on the protection method setUnprotectedRanges.
Today, I am facing the same problem but this time I do not make the mistake (as far as I can see).

I actually pass an array on ranges in A1 notation and the logs confirm that. I can assure you I am not drunk or drugged, may be only a bit tired, and I cannot see what is probably a trivial problem again.

Here is the script

```
  var thisSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var template = thisSheet.getRange("TemplateLineRecurrent")
  var forms = template.getFormulas()
  Logger.log(forms)
  var insertPos=template.getRow()
  //insert a new line
  thisSheet.insertRowsBefore(insertPos,1)
  //copy the template
  destRange = thisSheet.getRange(insertPos,template.getColumn(),1,template.getLastColumn()-template.getColumn()+1)
  destRange.setFormulas(forms)
  var p = thisSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var newRanges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    newRanges.push(ranges[i].getA1Notation());
  } 
  r=thisSheet.getRange(insertPos,destRange.getColumn(),1,5).getA1Notation()
  Logger.log(r)
  newRanges.push(r)
  Logger.log(newRanges)
  p.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);
```

and here is the matching log

```
Oct 28, 2023, 2:12:21 PM
Info
[[, , , , , =IF(E13>F13;E13-F13;0), =IF(F13>E13;F13-E13;0)]]
Oct 28, 2023, 2:12:22 PM
Info
B13:F13
Oct 28, 2023, 2:12:22 PM
Info
[C7:F12, B29, B7:B12, B13:F13]
Oct 28, 2023, 2:12:22 PM
Error
Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Protection.setUnprotectedRanges.
    at AddRecurrentLine(WebAppScripts:73:5)
    at myMacros(WebAppScripts:36:7)
    at doGet(WebAppScripts:2:20)
```

Comment: Tip: `console` is better than `Logger`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the argument of `setUnprotectedRanges(ranges)` method is `Range[]`. In your script, it seems that an array including the A1Notation is used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Protection.setUnprotectedRanges.`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
p.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);
```

#### To:

```
p.setUnprotectedRanges(thisSheet.getRangeList(newRanges).getRanges());
```

- By this, `thisSheet.getRangeList(newRanges).getRanges()` is `Range[]` of `thisSheet`.

#### References:

- [setUnprotectedRanges(ranges)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))

Comment: Thank you very much. I simply deleted the getA1Notation before pushing to newRanges.

Comment: @Meaulnes Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Thank you very much. I simply deleted the getA1Notation before pushing to newRanges.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the issue of my answer? I thought that your question was to remove your error of `The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Protection.setUnprotectedRanges.`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding was not correct, I apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Comment: @Tanaike OP is just saying "I deleted `.getA1Notation()` here: `newRanges.push(ranges[i].getA1Notation()); }`- thanks to the idea in your answer"

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I could understand it. I had thought that OP wanted to confirm the values in newRanges. So, I proposed the above modification without removing `getA1Notation()`. But, from `I simply deleted the getA1Notation before pushing to newRanges.` and your reply, I understood that my guess was not correct. But, I'm glad because I understood that OP's issue was resolved.

Comment: @Meaulnes Now, I understood your reply. I'm glad your issue was resolved.